# Avoiding muscle atrophy from muscle injury

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, anatomy, humanoid

My Keplerians are humanoids but they have a special organ and special hormones for protein storage. Not only that but they don't get muscle atrophy from injury. Take the abdominal muscles for example. If a Keplerian who wants to build muscle does too many bodyweight exercises, they will get a first degree muscle injury:
[image]
Sort of like this, injured and swollen but still intact(tears are microscopic). When they get this injury, a hormone is released to break the stored protein down into amino acids and bring it to the injured muscle. Why stored protein? Well my Keplerians naturally eat a high protein diet so eating even more protein is not needed. There will be some muscle growth after this injury heals.

If they do this but with a weight that they are used to carrying as a load, the injury is going to be worse. It will be a second degree muscle injury:
[image]

This means that the muscle, macroscopically is torn but not completely torn. There won't be a hole, just a tear or possibly multiple tears This still leads to muscle growth.

Now, if the weight is not what they are used to carrying as a load but instead heavier, the injury is going to be even worse. The muscle will rupture. It might not rupture completely but there certainly will be a hole where the abdominal muscles are supposed to be.
[image]

That is a third degree muscle tear and as you can see from the image, it leads to hernias. Complete rest though can prevent these hernias from occuring. It might lead to a rash or a backache but that is certainly better than a hernia. So much protein is used to heal a third degree muscle tear that none goes to muscle growth. However, with their naturally high protein diet, muscle breakdown is prevented. So muscle mass is conserved.

**But is this plausible? Is it plausible that muscle injury leads to muscle growth even when it is second degree? Is it plausible that muscle mass is conserved in a third degree muscle injury simply due to a naturally high protein intake? What would prevent this from being plausible?**

Comment: If a muscle is torn macroscopically, how would it grow? First and foremost, the growth needs to repair the tear.

Comment: But a high protein diet can compensate for that by getting more protein into the bloodstream. And since they have a high protein diet naturally, that means that they can still get muscle growth, even with a second degree muscle injury.

Comment: the current muscle growth mechanism relies on exercise. If a muscle is not exercising, it's not growing, even if protein is plentiful. You need to address this detail.

Comment: (a) Too many questions.  One question at a time, please.  (b) Hard to read post, please reduce the size of your images.  (c) No, it isn't plausible.  @Alexander is 100% correct. Muscle mass increases more quickly with protein + exercise, but exercise alone (with minimal protein intake) will also do it.  No exercise = muscle atrophy.  All the protein in the world won't stop atrophy if exercise is entirely removed (I know this for a fact due to an injury as a teen).

Answer (score 2):

Torn muscle cells are repaired by myosatellite cells.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosatellite_cell

> Myosatellite cells or satellite cells are small multipotent cells with
>   virtually no cytoplasm found in mature muscle. Satellite cells are
>   precursors to skeletal muscle cells, able to give rise to satellite
>   cells or differentiated skeletal muscle cells. They have the potential
>   to provide additional myonuclei to their parent muscle fiber, or
>   return to a quiescent state.  More specifically, upon activation,
>   satellite cells can re-enter the cell cycle to proliferate and
>   differentiate into myoblasts.

Your creatures have loads of these myosatellite cells and they are very enthusiastic.  Damage of any sort spurs them into action to a much greater degree that is the case for humans.  Often their action repairs the muscle to a greater strength / muscle fiber density than was the case before the damage occurred.

No special diet required.